# bash can't find sudo command on friendlyarm

Tags: linux, bash, arm, sudo

I'm trying to work with this friendlyarm 9 board I got recently but it can't find some basic bash commands and I couldn't find a solution for it anywhere. 
When I type any command with sudo or even when I type sudo alone I get

> /bin/sh: sudo: not found

It is the same when I type bash:

> /bin/sh: bash: not found

Should I add something to its PATH? or anything like that?

I asked it here cause I thought it's a linux problem. If it's not can you tell me where to ask about it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you find the `sudo` binary? By the way, maybe it's better to ask this on [SE]

Comment: where is its binary?

Comment: Usually in `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Usually, but not necessarily. It might be installed anywhere else, if at all. Note that friendlyarm probably doesn't house a complete desktop linux installation and so might not have all commands installed that you are used to. You can use `su` instead to gain superuser powers (if you aren't root already) and you can use whatever shell is available. There's not only `bash`.

Comment: no it's not there, I tried find sudo. but it didn't find anything

Comment: i tried su, but it get permission denied error for the bash script i wanna lunch

Comment: Also try to login as root directly by whatever means you use to login into the board.

Comment: Also note that `su` is called differently in comparison to `sudo`. `sudo test.sh` would translate to `su -c test.sh`. And you have to give the root password to `su` if you don't specify a different user. In contrast, on several desktop distros, `sudo` is configured to ask for the calling user's password instead by default.

Comment: su -c test.sh also gets permission denied. what's wrong with this? the bash file contains some export commands and one "exec" which is supposed to lunch my application

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your problem without the exact circumstances when it prints the error message. Did `su` ask you for a password at all? If not, it probably lacks the necessary permissions to be executed by non-root users (Try changing them as root). Also, since it's not a programming question, I'd consider [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) more appropriate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31315/discussion-between-soroosh-strife-and-blubberdiblub)

Answer (score 1):

it seems this version of linux im using doesn't support some bash commands and thus i didn't need them. getting permission denied was a result of the script not having executable permissions. Thanx to [blubberdiblub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794539/blubberdiblub) I set the permissions for it to run.

Comment: You seem to be running `bin/sh`, which might not be a bash shell at all. Maybe the title should be "My shell can not find the command "sudo" or "bash" ".

Comment: Also remember that `sudo` is not a standard app, it is standard in the Debian world, not in Linux in general. It is definitely not a `bash` command and it is not strange not to find it installed by default.